# Disable Excel 2016 "Share" on specific document

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Is it possible to disable the Excel 2016 "Share" option on a specific document only? I have previously used CustomUI XML to remove all unwanted ribbons buttons etc. for a specific document that I don't want users to send to others or to save locally. But Office 2016 adds a button in the File tab (as well as in the top right corner) that allows users to easily share (as Email attachment, etc.) the document with others.

I would like to prevent that, and I can see that it is possible via a GPO (http://www.urtech.ca/2017/03/solved-disable-share-button-office-2016-using-gpo/) but I don't want this option to be disabled for everything - just this single document. I have tried all the options in CustomUI including the TabShare but it turns of everything except the "Share" button.

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <backstage>
        <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileOpen" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileClose" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileExit" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="HistoryTab" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="OfficeFeedback" visible="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabInfo" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabRecent" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabPrint" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false" enabled="false" />
        <tab idMso="TabHelp" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabPublish" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabSave" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabOfficeStart" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
    <tab idMso="Publish2Tab" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
    <tab idMso="TabOfficeFeedback" visible="false" enabled="false"/>
    </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Comment: you can probably find the control id by looping the commandbars https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2009/04/30/here-is-a-way-to-get-the-id-of-a-built-in-outlook-command-bar-menu-norm-estabrook/, but not sure if that can be used in the customUI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd943885?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396